# Postgres combining multiple Indexes

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have the following table/indexes -

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
   coords geography(Point,4326), 
   user_id varchar(50), 
   created_at timestamp
);
CREATE INDEX ix_coords ON test USING GIST (coords);
CREATE INDEX ix_user_id ON test (user_id);
CREATE INDEX ix_created_at ON test (created_at DESC);
```

This is the query I want to execute:

```
select * 
from updates 
where ST_DWithin(coords, ST_MakePoint(-126.4, 45.32)::geography, 30000) 
and user_id='3212312' 
order by created_at desc
limit 60
```

When I run the query it only uses `ix_coords` index. How can I ensure that Postgres uses `ix_user_id` and `ix_created_at` index as well for the query?

This is a new table in which I did bulk insert of production data. Total rows in the `test` table: **15,069,489**

I am running PostgreSQL 9.2.1 (with Postgis) with (effective_cache_size = 2GB). This is my local OSX with 16GB RAM, Core i7/2.5 GHz, non-SSD disk.

Adding the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output -

```
Limit  (cost=71.64..71.65 rows=1 width=280) (actual time=1278.652..1278.665 rows=60 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=71.64..71.65 rows=1 width=280) (actual time=1278.651..1278.662 rows=60 loops=1)
         Sort Key: created_at
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 33kB
         ->  Index Scan using ix_coords on test  (cost=0.00..71.63 rows=1 width=280) (actual time=0.198..1278.227 rows=178 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (coords && '0101000020E61000006666666666E63C40C3F5285C8F824440'::geography)
               Filter: (((user_id)::text = '4f1092000b921a000100015c'::text) AND ('0101000020E61000006666666666E63C40C3F5285C8F824440'::geography && _st_expand(coords, 30000::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin(coords, '0101000020E61000006666666666E63C40C3F5285C8F824440'::geography, 30000::double precision, true))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 3122459
 Total runtime: 1278.701 ms
```

UPDATE:

Based on the suggestions below I tried index on cords + user_id:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_coords_and_user_id ON updates USING GIST (coords, user_id);
```

..but get the following error:

```
ERROR:  data type character varying has no default operator class for access method "gist"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
```

UPDATE:

So the `CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;` solved the btree/gist compound index issue. And now my index looks like

```
CREATE INDEX ix_coords_user_id_created_at ON test USING GIST (coords, user_id, created_at);
```

NOTE: btree_gist does not accept DESC/ASC.

New query plan:

```
Limit  (cost=134.99..135.00 rows=1 width=280) (actual time=273.282..273.292 rows=60 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=134.99..135.00 rows=1 width=280) (actual time=273.281..273.285 rows=60 loops=1)
         Sort Key: created_at
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 41kB
         ->  Index Scan using ix_updates_coords_user_id_created_at on updates  (cost=0.00..134.98 rows=1 width=280) (actual time=0.406..273.110 rows=115 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((coords && '0101000020E61000006666666666E63C40C3F5285C8F824440'::geography) AND ((user_id)::text = '4e952bb5b9a77200010019ad'::text))
               Filter: (('0101000020E61000006666666666E63C40C3F5285C8F824440'::geography && _st_expand(coords, 30000::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin(coords, '0101000020E61000006666666666E63C40C3F5285C8F824440'::geography, 30000::double precision, true))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Total runtime: 273.331 ms
```

The query is performing better than before, almost a second better but still not great. I guess this is the best that I can get?? I was hoping somewhere around 60-80ms. Also taking `order by created_at desc` from the query, shaves off another 100ms, meaning it is unable to use the index. Anyway to fix this?

Comment: Postgres uses a cost based planner.  Even if it CAN use the index, it might not be as fast as not using it.  You can play with random_page_cost and the cpu* cost vars to see if you can talk it into using those indexes. Use explain analyze <yourqueryhere> to see what it decides to do and how fast it is.

Comment: Usage of an index also depends on the available statistics. How many rows actually have `user_id='3212312'` ? Have you done a `vacuum analyze` before this query (at least after populating the table) ?

Comment: To see what it does when the `ix_coords` index isn't available - whether it can use the other index and what the cost is - try `BEGIN; DROP INDEX ix_coords ON thetable; EXPLAIN ANALYZE the_query; ROLLBACK;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if Pg can combine a GiST index and regular b-tree indexes with a bitmap index scan, but I suspect not. You may be getting the best result you can without adding a `user_id` column to your GiST index (and consequently making it bigger and slower for other queries that don't use `user_id`).

As an experiment you could:

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
CREATE INDEX ix_coords_and_user_id ON test USING GIST (coords, user_id);
```

which is likely to result in a big index, but might boost that query - if it works. Be aware that maintaining such an index will significantly slow `INSERT` and `UPDATE`s. If you drop the old `ix_coords` your queries will use `ix_coords_and_user_id` even if they don't filter on `user_id`, but it'll be slower than `ix_coords`. Keeping both will make the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` slowdown even worse.

See [btree-gist](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html)

---

(*Obsoleted by edit to question that changes the question completely; when written the user had a multicolumn index they've now split into two separate ones*):

You don't seem to be filtering or sorting on `user_id`, only `create_date`. Pg won't (can't?) use only the second term of a multi-column index like `(user_id, create_date)`, it needs use of the first item too.

If you want to index `create_date`, create a separate index for it. If you use and need the `(user_id, create_date)` index and don't generally use just `user_id` alone, see if you can reverse the column order. Alternately create two independent indexes,  `(user_id)` and `(create_date)`.  When both columns are needed Pg can combine the two indepependent indexes using a bitmap index scan.

Comment: sorry I had some typos in the my question, had mixed id & user_id, basically its just "user_id".

Comment: I have added the explain analyze output. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @user310525 You seem to have completely changed your index definitions by splitting `ix_created_at`'s `user_id` component into a new index. Was the old one just wrong? Or have you changed your setup and not explained that? If you change it, better to explain and add new material, not just silently change what's there so old answers no longer make sense in context.

Comment: PostgreSQL can use the second term of a multi-column index, but it's often more expensive than ignoring the index entirely and going straight to the table. See [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/indexes-multicolumn.html) for more.

Comment: @CraigRinger postgres wont let me create a gist index on coords + user_id?? I have updated the original question.

Comment: @user310525 Looks like you need the [`btree_gist` extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html) installed. `CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;`. Honestly, though, I really doubt you'll gain much.

Comment: @CraigRinger see my update, the btree_gist index did improve the query performance, thanks a lot. Since I need created_at sort, I created compound index on coords + user_id + created_at. But it seems that it doesnt have any affect on order by and the sort on created_at takes about 100ms?? :(

Comment: @user310525 I don't think an index is going to help for that bit. What if you bump up `work_mem`? Try `SET work_mem = 2MB`

Comment: @user310525 Removing the unused column in the index will make it faster. You can also try reordering it as (user_id, coords) and see if that performs better.

Answer (score 2):

I think Craig is correct with his answer, but I just wanted to add a few things (and it wouldn't fit in a comment)

You have to work pretty hard to *force* PostgreSQL to use an index.  The Query optimizer is smart and there are times where it will believe that a sequential table scan will be faster.  It is usually right! :)  But, you can play with some settings (such as seq_page_cost, random_page_cost, etc) you can play with to try and get it to favor an index.  Here is a link to some of the [configurations](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-query.html) that you might want to examine if you feel like it is not making the correct decision.  But, again...  my experience is that most of the time, Postgres is smarter than I am!  :)

Hope this helps you (or someone in the future).